# How to check JSON format validation?

Tags: python, json

My program gets a JSON file that has an information for service.
Before run the service program, I want to check if the JSON file is valide(Only check whether all necessary keys exist).
Below is the standard(necessary datas) JSON format for this program:

```
{
    "service" : "Some Service Name"
    "customer" : {
        "lastName" : "Kim",
        "firstName" : "Bingbong",
        "age" : "99",
    }
}
```

Now I am checking the JSON file validation like this:

```
import json

def is_valid(json_file):

    json_data = json.load(open('data.json'))

    if json_data.get('service') == None:
        return False
    if json_data.get('customer').get('lastName') == None:
        return False
    if json_data.get('customer').get('firstName') == None:
        return False
    if json_data.get('customer').get('age') == None:
        return False

    return True
```

Actually, the JSON standard format has more than 20 keys. Is there any other way to check the JSON format?

Comment: This might help: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579135-validate-data-easily-with-json-schema/

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous (no experience, just stumbled across this recently).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might consider [`jsonschema`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) to validate your JSON. Here is a program that validates your example. To extend this to your "20 keys", add the key names to the `"required"` list.

```
import jsonschema
import json

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "customer": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["lastName", "firstName", "age"]}},
    "required": ["service", "customer"]
}

json_document = '''{
    "service" : "Some Service Name",
    "customer" : {
        "lastName" : "Kim",
        "firstName" : "Bingbong",
        "age" : "99"
    }
}'''

try:
    # Read in the JSON document
    datum = json.loads(json_document)
    # And validate the result
    jsonschema.validate(datum, schema)
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
    print("well-formed but invalid JSON:", e)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("poorly-formed text, not JSON:", e)
```

Resources:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema
- http://json-schema.org/example1.html

Comment: but how can I check if the `schema`'s format is correct? for instance, If I happen to forget write the type for the properties, how can I check this typo error?

Comment: Not sure if draft version matters, but I think your schema is wrong when tested in the latest version. Need to wrap `customer` inside `properties`. Try removing `lastName` from datum then you can see it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fail in case the required fields aren't actually passed: are you sure this is the right code (try removing one, say 'lastName', the `try-except` still doesn't except)?

Comment: Thanks, @gented! I appreciate the comment. I've fixed the example.

Comment: Thanks, @Cyker . I apologize for not responding sooner. I've fixed the example.

Answer (score 2):

If your finding the json schema syntax confusing. Create your json as you want it and then run it though [online-json-to-schema-converter](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter) and then use it in Rob's example above.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using of `jsonschema`(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) can perform thot for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, don’t check for None using `if x == None`, use `if x is None`

You might try to simplify it slightly by checking the keys using `set(json_data.keys()) == set(key1, key2, ...)`

That would need to be repeated for any nested dictionaries in your json structure. Using sets instead of lists has the benefit of sets being unordered so it doesn’t matter the order of the data in your json.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone does not want to use [jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) to validate then below code can be used to validate only the `keys` of `json` as requested in this question.

```
import json

def validateJsonKeys(myjson):

    if set(myjson.keys()) == {'service', 'customer'}:
        if set(myjson['customer'].keys()) == {'lastName', 'firstName', 'age'}:
            return True
        return False
    else:
        return False
```